# Need help to understand how ember.js Ember Data works

Tags: ember.js

I am very new to ember.js.

I have the following code which I need to change to retrieve data from the server using multiple models (using multiple JSON/RESTful calls).

This (single model version) WORKS:

> In app/routes/index.js:
>
> ```
> import Ember from 'ember';
>
> export default Ember.Route.extend({
>   model() {
>     return this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true});
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> and in wallet-balance.hbs:
>
> ```
> <div>Your Total Score: {{wallet.balance}} </div>
> ```

I changed to this and it WORKS:

> ```
> import Ember from 'ember';
> import RSVP from 'rsvp';
>
> export default Ember.Route.extend({
>   model() {
>     return RSVP.hash({
>       wallet: this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true})
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> and in wallet-balance.hbs:
>
> ```
> <div>Your Total Score: {{wallet.wallet.balance}} </div>
> ```

BUT if I change to the following ("wallet" -> "anythingelse"), it WON'T WORK:

> ```
> import Ember from 'ember';
> import RSVP from 'rsvp';
>
> export default Ember.Route.extend({
>   model() {
>     return RSVP.hash({
>       anythingelse: this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true})
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> and in wallet-balance.hbs:
>
> ```
> <div>Your Total Score: {{anythingelse.wallet.balance}} </div>
> ```

I'm trying to understand why. Where is it picking up from for the definintion "wallet" - and why changing to "anythingelse" won't work? Where else is the code for "wallet" referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components are isolated from their surroundings, so any data that the component needs has to be passed in. so you need to understand [how to pass properties to component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/).

I assume, in all the above three examples you are including `wallet-balance` component like this. 
`{{wallet-balance wallet=model}}`

If you want to make `{{anythingelse.wallet.balance}}` this one work for 3rd example, then you need to include the component like `{{wallet-balance wallet=model.anythingelse}}`

**For debugging in template hbs file, you can make use of [`log` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_log), like `{{log 'model object' model}}` this will print `model` object in console.**

Here is the reasoning behind the screen,

Whatever is returned from model hook will be set in corresponding controller's `model` property by default through `setupController` hook method.
In your case, you didn't override `setupController` so default behavior is applicable.

> `return this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true});`

- queryRecord will return `Promise` and it will be resolved to single record `wallet` and it will be set in controller's `model` property. now `model` is equivalent to single `wallet` record object. you can access it in template `{{model.balance}}

> `return RSVP.hash({
>         anythingelse: this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true})
>       });`

`queryRecord` will return `Promise` and it will be resolved to single record `wallet` and it will be set in inside the object `{anythingelse:walletRecord}` now model is equivalent to `{anythingelse:walletRecord}`. you can access it in template like `{{model.anythingelse.balance}}`

Comment: I see. So, "anythingelse" corresponds to "{{wallet.anythingelse.balance}}". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your model in [`setupController()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController).

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').queryRecord('wallet', {balance: true});
  },

  setupController(controller, wallet) {
    controller.set('wallet', wallet);
  }

});
```

Hope this helps.